# “A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I **disable this page validation entirely and for good** in ASP.NET MVC 3?

I have looked through the error message and the other questions with the same title. None of the suggested solutions help:

- I **do** have a

  ```
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  ```

  in the `<system.web>` section in `Web.config`.
- I also **do** have a `validateRequest="false"` attribute on the `<pages>...</pages>` element.

But I am still getting the error. What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line of code:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ValidateInputAttribute(false));
```

to the `Application_Start()` method.

Comment: Is there any method other than disabling validateRequest, since it threatens the security of the web site.

Answer (score 3):

Add `[AllowHtml]` to the action, parameter, or property.

**EDIT**: If you want to allow it anywhere, add `new ValidateInputAttribute(false)]` to `GlobalFilters.Filters`.

Comment: And if I have a million actions, parameters and properties? I don’t want to have to allow it for every one, I just want to disable the validation entirely, please.

Comment: ... Besides, that is semantically wrong. My properties do *not*, as a matter of fact, “allow HTML”. They simply allow *any plain text*, including plain text containing angle brackets.

Comment: @Timwi: See my edit.  Plain text containing angle brackets is what HTML refers to here.

Comment: `AllowHtml` is not an action filter (one that implements `IActionFilter`) so you cannot add it to the global filters. It's just a marker attribute. Or you were probably referring to the `ValidateInput` action filter?

Comment: @Timwi do you have actually *"a million [...] properties?"*

Comment: Is there any method other than disabling <code>validateRequest</code>, since it thretens the security of the web site.